# Set graph min interval globally in Grafana

Tags: grafana, monitoring, grafana-dashboard

Grafana has a minimum interval option on graph settings with the default value of 15s, this means regardless of how small the time frame is received data points will not be less than 15s apart. You can set this value to be less for a specific panel as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

But it's not very practical to do this for every panel in every dashboard considering a lot of them are also imported dashboards. Is there a way to set the default value for this option globally?

The Grafana server configuration page only lists the following options in the dashboard section (none seem to be related to minimum data interval) but maybe I should be looking somewhere else for this.

- versions_to_keep
- min_refresh_interval
- default_home_dashboard_path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Min Interval* has no global option, because it's highly dependable on data source in use.

Tool tip of the *Min Interval* option states:

> A lower limit for the interval. Recommended to be set to write frequency, for example `1m` if your data is written every minute. Default value can be set in data source settings for most data sources.

So, if you'll go through all your data sources, and adjust their options<sup>*</sup>, panels that have default values for *Min Interval* will assume those new adjusted settings.

---

<sup>*</sup> : Different data sources have different names for those options. Here is a couple examples: Prometheus - *Scrape interval*, MySQL - *Min time interval*. I don't think exhaustive list exists, so you'll need to find options for other data sources yourself.